# Select from two tables, order by date in both

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to show the latest entries in two tables, but order both by date.
I do not know how to show tables on here, so please work with me on this...

Right now I have

```
SELECT * FROM `doctrine_pubs` WHERE `status` = 'ACTIVE' ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

I also have

```
SELECT * FROM `doctrine_terms` ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

I would like to combine these two, but I don't want to show the results from one table, then the results from the other, but instead would like them combined and ordered by dates together.

Is this possible or would I have to create a single table to get this result?

Edit, here's the tables... I really do not know how to format these.

Table doctrine_terms

```
term_id | display   | acronym| definition      | reference | symbol | date       | changeType
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
698     | some term | ABC    | a bunch of text | Book6     | NA     | 1484136000 | NEW
```

Table doctrine_pubs

```
pub_id | number   | title           | date       | status | link
----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
123    | Book6    | some string here| 1484168496 | ACTIVE | www.example.com
```

Comment: I advice you to investigate or read about inner join

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Remember:  a result set has a fixed set of columns.  You don't get a different set of columns for each row.

Comment: Paste your table data, then mark it as code with `Ctl-k` to keep the formatting.

Comment: How is this a PHP question? Also it's hard to help without data or at least a the schema of both tables in question.

Comment: Use `union` command. But remember selecting same data types of columns.

Comment: That's the thing, the tables are different. Similar, but different. When I get to computer I'll post the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You codul use UNION
if the two table have have the same columns (number and type) you could use * otherwise you must explicatally select the named  cols like in the sample 
  (remember number and type must match between the two select  and use union all if you need  all resul  ... union if you need  distinct result)

```
  select t1.date, t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3 
  FROM `doctrine_pubs` as t1
  WHERE `status` = 'ACTIVE' 

  UNION ALL 
  select t2.date, t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3 
  FROM `doctrine_terms`  as t2
  ORDER BY `date` DESC
```